# Proper fstab options for the disk

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab

I have the following line in /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sdb3      /media/mybook    xfs     rw,auto,users                  0        0
```

The device is properly mounted and seen by root, but not by the normal user:

```
$ ls -al /media/
drwx-w---- 17  500 users 4096 2011-08-02 18:56 mybook
```

What should be changed in fstab to make it mount as rw for the normal user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo chmod a=rwx /media/mybook
```

The permission bits are stored on disk with XFS, you cannot override them with mount options.

Comment: thank you, it really helped. I assume that I should probably chown it as well, as it stores uid (500) from the old system